# Enthought Canopy 1.5.4 failed with IPython Notebook

Tags: enthought

I tried to update Canopy from 1.5.2 to recent 1.5.4 on Win7(32) and Win7(64) in many ways - by regular update, by clean update including uninstalling 1.5.2, deleting the appropriate folders - install 1.5.4 on the computer where there were no Canopy - but every time always the same.

It failed with the IPython Notebook. It can not open a new Notebook (without any message) and when I try to open an existing one, it is not possible - with the error:

### Unable to load file:'C:\Users....

### 403 Client Error: Forbidden

I had to clean it up and to clean reinstall 1.5.2 version which works fine.

Does anyone had similar experience?
Any comment would be appreciated.

Regards,
Radovan

[EDIT]The same from my Linux Mint when trying to update from 1.5.2 to 1.5.4 by regular updating

Comment: Radovan, we can't reproduce this. What happens if you open a Canopy Command Prompt from the Tools menu, type `ipython notebook` to open the notebook in a browser, and try from the browser? Also: is it possible that your User environment was corrupted and the difference is not in the Canopy version but in the fact that you did the cleanup before reinstalling 1.5.2?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for the answer.

Thank you for point me out about  'ipython notebook'

Comment: I again tried to do a clean install of 1.5.2. Among other AppData folders I even deleted **.ipython** folder from the user Appdata folder because I had 1.5.2 working GUI and 2.7.9 Python and 3.1.0 ipython ???

Now 1.5.2. GUI worked fine with Notebooks, but when I started **ipython notebook**  (Python 2.7.6, Ipython 2.3.1 finaly !!!) now, if I tried to open a new notebook this error appeared:

**Creating Notebook failed**:
_Unespected error while autosaving notebook: C:\Windows\system32\Untitled0.ipynb [Errno 17] No usable temporary file name found_

Do not dare to update now to 2.5.4

Comment: I found the answer by browsing this site, and it was by switching to say _C:\Users\Radovan Omorjan\Documents_ and then I could start also *ipython notebook*, open the new notebooks, etc. It also worked Ok in GUI. This is always with 1.5.2.

Comment: Then I again tried to update to 1.5.4. The same happened with Notebooks **Error 403**. I can notice that now the Python is 2.7.9 and Ipython 2.3.1 (the old one). Strating the **ipython notebook** will work and I can work with Noteboks (provided changing of folder previosly). I have a filling that I am in some kind of loop here. I am not sure which Ipython is in 1,5.4 - the old one 2.3.1 or the new one 3.1.0?

Comment: Either way, whatever I do:  
  
    Canopy GUI will always give me 403 Client Error: Forbidden
    although I could start and work with Ipython Notebook in the Browser

Comment: The same situation with 1.5.5 *Error 403* i still present with IPython notebook. The new one can not be opened. There is not even any message about it. You can open any new file except "New IPython Notebook". Unfortunately, I will have to give up from Canopy for the moment.

Comment: If you are creating new notebooks (rather than opening old ones that were created in IPython 2.x), it's probably best for now to use IPNB in a browser anyway, as described here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/63354850-Issues-with-IPython-notebook-running-in-the-Canopy-GUI-application -- you'll still have access to all the same packages that you've installed in the package manager and that you can access from the IPython terminal in the Canopy GUI.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the answer, but this will not solve our problem. This is actually an unpleasant problem for me and my students. We were using version 1.5.2 Canopy GUI in our teaching all the time. Now, they simply can not use 1.5.5. Canopy GUI because they can not neither open their Notebooks nor make a new one (Error 403). I still have no idea why is this happening. Therefore, I will have to explain that they have to stay with 1.5.2. because the recent 1.5.5. is simply not working in the way they are used to. Canopy GUI 1.5.5 is simply not working with IPython Notebooks.

Comment: I am not familiar with this issue, opening support ticket.